# Is there a way to display the radius of fluid control object?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I wonder if there's a way of showing the radius, because it's pretty hard for me to guess what size it is after i adjust it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this through a **driver** with a few *simple* steps.

1. **Right click** on the *"radius"* setting and select *"Add Driver"*.
2. **Add** an object as a visualizer for the size of the radius.
3. **Select** your *control* object again, and go to the ***graph editor.***
4. *Switch* to **driver** editing mode.
5. **Select** to driver you created, and **open** the properties panel with <kbd>n</kbd>.
6. **Scroll** down to the *variables* section and select the *visualizer object* you created earlier.
7. Now change the *type* to **X Scale**. *(we will scale x and y uniformly)*
8. As the *expression* to be used, type your **variable name.**

**Finished!** You can now select your circle, and  scale it to adjust the radius value.

You can also change the steps a little to edit the value and have it change the object.

- Instead of adding a driver to the "radius" value, add it to the scale of the circle.
- Change the transform channel of the driver to single property.
- Make sure the type is set to object.
- Set the object to your fluid controller
- Right click and copy the data path to the radius property.
- Paste it into the RNA path section (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>)
- You can now right click on your driver to copy and paste it for the "y" scale as well.

  Notes:
- These tips work for any object, such as a sphere.
- You may need to change which frame of the animation you are on for the changes to take effect. Otherwise, Blender may not reload the data.

I hope this helps. Check out this little gif I made of the steps.

[image]

Comment: Do you saggest me to create a circle at origin of my control object and set it's dimensions to radius size?

Comment: What object do you want to measure? What is your "fluid control object"? Is it a circle, a forcefield, or a setting somewhere?

Comment: Whatever object has the physics for fluid control on it, select that, and it will show the dimensions in the properties panel.

Comment: It's a smaller double of a letter. And I was talking about some graphical display of the radius setting. It's dimensions wont help i think

Comment: Sorry it took me so long. I have the answer here. I will post it soon (I hope).

Comment: Not sure if this will help: In the Properties panel click on the little box, the one between World and Constraints and there's a Display section.  In that try ticking the Bounds box and/or changing the Maximum Draw Type to Bounds.

Comment: That is an awesome solution, Uncle Snail. Thank you very much for your time and answer!

Comment: Okay, great! If you have any more problems, please let me know.

Comment: Yeah, looks like I have one. =) Well, the first way works fine, but the second doesn't affect circle's  scale.

Comment: Did you try changing frames? It may not show the results until you switch to another frame, because it does not reload mesh data.

Comment: Yes, I did. But still nothing happend

Comment: Hmmm.... I don't know what's happening. Perhaps you missed a step. I don't think I put all the steps in the second method, just the ones that are different from the first method... but I don't see any that are missing. Try undoing whatever you did, and starting with the scale of the circle at 1, and the radius (value) at 0.5. These "default" values will maybe help.

Comment: Hmm, at the 5th try on clean project without changing any steps it finally did it, of course after moving to another frame. Thank you) But now I'm also interested in auto-updating the size with changing the radius. How can it be done?

Comment: It can be done through a script. You need a more expert person to know what script though. :) You just need to tell Blender to update the mesh information every time a value is changed. ATM, blender is only updating the meshes when it knows there could have been a change, and that doesn't include drivers atm, but it does include frame change. It helps save performance so that it isn't recalculating the meshes constantly. I don't know of a way to do that without a script. Doing other things will recalculate as well. That's my understanding of the situation anyway.

Comment: It's sort of like having to change the number of particles on a particle system to reset Blender's cache so that you can start fresh. Otherwise it just remembers what you had before. So if you add a physics object or something you need blender to recalculate that system, so you change a value in the system that requires a recalculation. If Blender recalculated every time you added or moved a physics object though, even particle systems not affected would reload, losing data you wanted to keep and causing performance loss.